PhpStorm freezes with Copilot
In recent months, PhpStorm has shown freezes whenever Copilot is active and suggests some code, especially if I type something different from what is suggested.
Anyone has seen something like this? Any suggestion?
Specs:

Win 11
Intel i7 13º
RTX 4050
16GB DDR5

Per hour, I uninstall Copilot plugin.

The real problem is the version of phpstorm.
After 2024.1 this crashes will happen.
The solution is downgrade to last 2023 version (2023.3.7)
